# How to do a sql search query with a datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to use the datetimepicker in a WHERE Clause to search for a few columns on a particular date. Could anyone help me, I don't know if I should use a button to initialize the select query or what I have now is enough. I would like to be able to select the date multiple times.

```
Private Sub FrmBookings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dtpBookings.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtpBookings.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"




    Dim bsql As String = "select rooms.RoomID as 'Room Number',roomType.RoomTypeName , rooms.Ensuite, 
customers.fname, customers.lname, booking.arrivaldate, booking.departuredate, br.status
From bookedrooms br
Left Join booking ON booking.BookingID = br.brBookingID
Left Join rooms ON br.brRoomID = rooms.RoomID 
Left Join roomtype on rooms.RoomTypeID = roomtype.RoomTypeID
Left Join customers ON customers.CustomerID = booking.BCustomerID
WHERE booking.arrivaldate = '" + dtpBookings.Value.ToString() + "'"

    DgvBookings.DataSource = display(bsql, "bookedrooms")

End Sub
```

Comment: Please see http://bobby-tables.com for advice on [why you should never write SQLs that way](https://coar.risc.anl.gov/consequences-of-sql-injection-attacks/).. Yes, it's a limited risk in this particular case given the source datatype, but as a general principle you should never take data from something the user can manipulate and put it straight into an SQL string

Comment: If you want to do a date range, then storing your dates as text in dd/mm/yyyy format (if that's how you've done it; just because you set that as a custom format of the control doesn't mean that calling toString on the date the control has will produce a dd/mm/yyyy formatted string) will make your life really hard work. Store your dates as yyyy-MM-dd or in an int as the number of seconds since the epoch then you stand a chance of using > and < operators

Comment: How is your DateTimePicker going to have a value selected by the user in the Form.Load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we pass the the value from the `DateTimePicker` to the function we add a format string to the `.ToString` method. I hope this matches exactly the way you have stored the dates in the database.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DgvBookings.DataSource = GetRoomCustomerData(dtpBookings.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
End Sub

Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function GetRoomCustomerData(ArrDate As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim bsql As String = "select rooms.RoomID as 'Room Number',roomType.RoomTypeName , rooms.Ensuite, customers.fname, customers.lname, booking.arrivaldate, booking.departuredate, br.status
                            From bookedrooms br
                            Left Join booking ON booking.BookingID = br.brBookingID
                            Left Join rooms ON br.brRoomID = rooms.RoomID 
                            Left Join roomtype on rooms.RoomTypeID = roomtype.RoomTypeID
                            Left Join customers ON customers.CustomerID = booking.BCustomerID
                            WHERE booking.arrivaldate = @Date;"
    Using cn As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SQLiteCommand(bsql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", DbType.String).Value = ArrDate
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```